# How to determine the color hue?

Tags: c#, colors

let's say that I have a HEX color #a08040. How can I determine in C#, if that color is the one of the many hues of the Brown color ?

In the other words, I have 4 colors: Brown, Red, Black, Gray.

How to determine what color hue is my HEX color?

Comment: Perhaps [the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.gethue.aspx) may be of interest?

Comment: See [hue on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hue): "brown [...] is a dark orange, and pink, a light red with reduced chroma". If I understand correctly there's no hue specific to brown

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using WinForms, the [`Color.GetHue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.gethue.aspx) method will do exactly what you want.

**Edit**
Unfortunately, there is no WPF equivalent to `GetHue`, you'll have to convert to a WinForms Color if you want to use `GetHue` from WPF. You could also compute the Hue yourself, if you're feeling frisky... [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hue) has the formula you'd need to use.